# Beautiful soup class search returning null or only 1 value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BS to pull pricing and color swatches for shirts pricing comes through "fine" but i'm having an issue with the swatches I can either only get 1 or it returns as null

ignore the price variable it works for now
I'm using zenrows as well if that has any affect but I don't think it does

https://www.sanmar.com/p/2383_RoyClsNvy?text=s508 this is one of the urls I'm trying to scrape

```
async def call_url(url):
    try:
        response = await client.get_async(url)
        if (response.ok):
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
            prices = soup.find_all(class_='price')[0].get_text()
            price1 = prices[15]
            price2 = prices[16]
            price3 = prices[17]
            price4 = prices[18]
            price5 = prices[19]
            price = price1 + price2 + price3 + price4 + price5
            newprice = "=" + price + "+ 8"
            return {
                "style": soup.find_all(class_= 'product-style-number')[0].get_text(),
                "price": price,
                "new price": newprice,
                "colors": soup.find_all(class_='swatches')[0].get_text()
            }
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

this returns the first swatch for me and

```
async def call_url(url):
    try:
        response = await client.get_async(url)
        if (response.ok):
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
            prices = soup.find_all(class_='price')[0].get_text()
            price1 = prices[15]
            price2 = prices[16]
            price3 = prices[17]
            price4 = prices[18]
            price5 = prices[19]
            price = price1 + price2 + price3 + price4 + price5
            newprice = "=" + price + "+ 8"
            colors = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'swatch-name'})[0].get_text()
            for color in colors:
                swatch = [color]
            return {
                "style": soup.find_all(class_= 'product-style-number')[0].get_text(),
                "price": price,
                "new price": newprice,
                "colors": swatch
            }
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

returns null

Comment: The index `[0]` makes it only process the first element that each `find_all()` finds. You might as well just use `find()` instead of `find_all()`.

Comment: `colors` is a string, so `for color in colors:` is iterating over the characters in the string. At the end of the loop, `swatch` will contain just the last character, since you're not appending to the list, you're replacing it each time through.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 1):

You're only processing the first swatch because you use the `[0]` index. You need to loop over all the items found by `.find_all()`. You can do this in a list comprehension to get a list of all the swatches.

You can simplify the code for `price` using a slice instead of creating 5 variables and concatenating.

In cases where you only want the first matching element, use `.find()` instead of `.find_all()[0]`.

The `class="swatch-name"` elements are `span`, not `div`.

```
async def call_url(url):
    try:
        response = await client.get_async(url)
        if (response.ok):
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
            prices = soup.find(class_='price').get_text()
            price = prices[15:20]
            newprice = "=" + price + "+ 8"
            colors = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'swatch-name'})
            swatches = [color.get_text() for color in colors]
            return {
                "style": soup.find(class_= 'product-style-number').get_text(),
                "price": price,
                "new price": newprice,
                "colors": swatches
            }
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

Comment: idk why but it is still returning null with this setup

Comment: Maybe you're getting an exception. Print the error instead of using `pass`

Comment: If it can't find the elements you're searching for, it will get an error trying to use `.get_text()`.

Comment: well no error is being printed and my old code also isn't working now

Comment: I don't see how it can return null, unless `response.ok` is false.

Comment: yeah that's kinda how ive felt I've tried like 10 different things and they'll work individually but then when i add it to the full snippet it just stops, makes no sense

Comment: `swatch-name` is a `<span>`, not `<div>`: `<span class="swatch-name">Black/ Light Stone</span>`

Comment: ahhhh so it is i don't know how to read

Comment: I didn't get None, I got an empty list in the `colors`.

Comment: yeah by itself it returned an empty list but when i plugged it into the full snippet thats when it would return null, but for some reason th efull snippet still returns null even though it all worked separately and when i use "colors": soup.find_all(class_='swatches')[0].get_text()

Comment: I just tested my code, except I used `requests.get()` instead of `client.get_async()`.

Comment: ah i figured out my issue, I was using zenrows api to make several request at once and i used up all my free uses apparently